# How can I test functioning of internal component (sensors, NFC, pedometer etc...)

Tags: applications, hardware, lg, lg-g3

I recently dropped my LG G3 in water. I opened it and let it dry for a long time.

It now work properly but some components does not seems to work anymore. For example light sensor, proximity sensor or pedometer seems broken.

Is there any way, or application, to have a full check-up of my phone component to see what is going on ? I want to see if all component are still detected or not and if I can do anything about it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these :

### Sensor Kinetics

The [Sensor Kinetics app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innoventions.sensorkinetics&hl=en) is an advanced monitor for the standard sensors that are available on Android devices. It offers a comprehensive look at the dynamics of the combined functionality of the sensors. The app demonstrates the use of each of the sensors and provides a look at the charts associated with each of them to know how fast the sensors are operating. The chart viewers allow users to measure the accuracy and behavior of the sensors.

<sub>(Click Image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

### Sensor Box for Android

[Sensor Box for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.androidsensorbox&hl=en) detects all available sensors on your Android device, and vividly shows you how they work with amazing graphics. Sensor Box for Android also tells you which sensors are supported by the hardware, and provides extremely useful sensor tools that could be used in our daily life.

[image: Sensor Box]

### Sensor Test

The Sensor Test application is a capable tool that is ultimately designed with the aim to detect the functionality of each of the sensors that are available on the user’s Android device. It displays the default sensors and shows the real time data and information of each sensor. This app provides support to Triggers sensors and supports devices running on Android 4.3 and above.

### Phone Tester

The Phone Tester is an application that lets users to analyze and detect if the components and hardware of their device are operating correctly. Apart from checking the functionality of the sensors on the device, users can also detect Wi-Fi, telephony, GPS, multi-touch, battery and system information. The app also comes in a Pro version that shows more information including phone memory, CPU speed and SD card memory without any ads.

### AndroSensor

The AndroSensor is a complete diagnostic tool allows users to know everything about their Android device and its status. It supports all the sensors on the device and detail on which of these sensors actually work or which of them are supports by the device hardware. The tool displays the real time sensor details in both graphical and text form and users can also record sensor data using the AndroSensor QuickBar into a CSV file.

### Sensor Checker

Sensor Tester checks the functionality from Your Android Device. Many Apps use sensors, but it is possible that Your device doesn´t support these sensors or are defective. With Sensor Checker You see which sensors are supported and if they work right. An example for a sensor app is a magnetic field sensor app like compass, or some apps where You have to shake your device.

Try also: [Sensors Multitool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wered.sensorsmultitool) & [Sensors Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=asd.vector.sensor)

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answers. Moreover I used CPU-Z and Elixir. witch confirmed me that most of my sensors were broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lg G3 hidden testing menu to test all the components

Depending on the carrier, your codes will be different. Check out the list below:

- AT&T: 3845#*850#
- Sprint: 5689#*990#
- T-Mobile: 3845#*851#
- Verizon Wireless: ##228378 (+ send)
- International Models: 3845#*855#

Just dial the codes in your dialer.

Source:http://lg-g3.wonderhowto.com/how-to/unlock-hidden-menu-run-diagnostic-test-your-lg-g3-0156740/

Comment: Where is the source? See [How to reference material written by others](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).