# NFC on S4 doesn't work at all

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, nfc

I have an S4 with which I try the Yubikey Neo with NFC on. I also tried another tag but I can't get any response from the phone whatsoever. Not even a beep. NFC is turned on for sure.

I bought an (relatively) expensive original battery (not from any suspicious ebay dealer) and it says Near Field Communication on it, as I understand the antenna is located ontop of the battery.

Does anyone have any ideas why it doesn't work? Is there a way I can test if the NFC is completely dead, or some logs I can look into? I have tested various apps for my tags but can't seen anything.

Comment: There is nothing related to NFC marqued on batteries, original or fake! What you bought seems to be a fake, even though it was expensive. And what do you mran by the antenna is located obtop of the battery? Didn't you find any option in the settings about NFC?

Comment: Well, as I understand it, the NFC antenna for the S4 is located on the outside of the battery. Have a look at http://static.trustedreviews.com/94/000029781/1f6a_orh500w750/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Battery.jpg . It clearly says "Near Field Communication" on it.

Comment: I can see a rectangular pattern on my battery so it seems the antenna would really be there.

Comment: The antenna is located on the back cover. Not on the battery itself. Check if there is an option related to NFC in the Settings.

Comment: You mean the plastic case? I highly doubt that. Could you refer to some source pointing to that that is the case? First of all, there are no electrical connections to the cheap plastic cover.

Comment: I don't own an S4, but never heard that phone manufacturers place antennas on [removable] batteries.

Comment: Please google it.

Comment: I did, and found nothing  related to this. Except one thread on XDA where it is mentioned on the battery itself.

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/8x9e93.jpg

Comment: You are right on NFC being on battery, it is the RFID which is on the reader. AFAIK,  battery logs or other logs do not provide view of NFC circuit working. My best guess would be faulty battery, syncs you have tried multiple tags / apps. Unfortunately, expensive doesn't mean original +1

Comment: This is the second battery not working though...

Comment: You can use apps mentioned here and in comments to confirm if the NFC functionality is working on your device from sensor perspective http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120232/131553 . Of it isn't there is little one can do except expensive hardware trading replacement

Comment: Can you let me the serial number on the battery? I mean the model number printed on it- it should be same as that of original battery

Comment: Also how many terminals does it have? Did it work fine with original battery?

Comment: Ser#: AA1H721WS/2-B   ...Maybe it worked. Many batteries since I last tried. 4 terminals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54004/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-johnytex).

Answer (score 1):

Luckily a friend of mine has an S4, here its  back. See the 4 gold metallic pins? Those are  the NFC  antennas connectors[image]

The antenna is on the back cover, not visible on the photo bellow, his back cover is not an original one, so no NFC antenna. 
[image]

It doesn't make sense the NFC antenna be ON THE BATTERY ITSELF! Despite the fact  is it written on the battery. My S5 battery also has Near Field Communication writing on it.

If NFC doesn't work, you should check if your back cover has something similar to this from my S5: [image]

EDIT:

Effectively, [the  battery contains a built-in NFC antenna.](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/octopuspayment/index_m.html) And it is recommended to handle the battery carefully to avoid damaging the NFC antenna, may be that's what happened to you.

Comment: Could we get some clarity into this subject? Someone?

Comment: I suspect one of the terminals are for charging: https://www.technobezz.com/how-to-add-qi-wireless-charging-to-the-galaxy-note-2/

Comment: I wonder if it can also work as an ordinary NFC antenna?

Comment: http://www.andytags.com/blog/can-you-use-nfc-and-qi-wireless-charging-or-is-there-incompatibility#.WKxJUFf8tpg

Comment: Which one is for charging? The connectors in the right are for the NFC.

Comment: Which ones do you mean?

Comment: The 2 at the right side, above SIM card slot. Below R1 mark. (Check the first image)

Comment: It turns out that you were right. On some models, the NFC antenna is really located on the battery. I Just looked closely to an S4 battery and there you can clearly see the antenna.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was the battery that didn't work. I tested with the battery of another phone that worked -and then it worked!

The battery that worked had serial#:

> YS1DC02FS/2-B

While the battery that didn't work (fresh from the store):

> AA1H721WS/2-B

All the batteries that didn't work started with

> AA...

Someone else hinted me in that direction in another thread. Now what's up with batteries whose serials are starting with AA? It says NFC on them and the antenna is visible through the decal. Why don't they work? One of them had original laser markings that I read none of the fakes usually have. What's going on? Someone?

something